# Add wind to trajectory of a projectile

Tags: calculus, geometry, physics, algebraic-curves

I am searching for a solution for my problem concerning the trajectory of projectiles. I have the following formulas to calculate the $x$, $y$-coordinates at any given time:

\begin{align*}
  x &=
  (\text{velocity} \times \cos \alpha \times \text{time})+
  \left(
    \frac{\text{wind}}{2} \times \text{time}^2
  \right) \tag{1}\\
  y &=
  (\text{velocity} \times \sin \alpha \times \text{time})+
  \left(
    \frac{\text{gravity}}{2} \times \text{time}^2
  \right)\tag{2}
\end{align*}

This works perfectly good, now I would like to calculate from a certain point $(x,y)$ with a fixed angle $\alpha$.  The required velocity,

$$\text{velocity} = \frac{x}{\cos \alpha} \times
  \left[
    \frac{\text{gravity}}{2(x\tan \alpha - y)}
  \right]\tag{3}$$

This works if I set wind to zero, but as soon as it is greater/smaller, it doesn't work anymore. What am I missing in the last formula to get the right result with wind?

Comment: Wind plays role of velocity not acceleration

Comment: Do you obtain (3) from (1) and (2).?

Comment: (3) is independent of the other 2

Comment: How did you obtain. intuition.? It's dimension is wrong.

Comment: Part intuition / part searching on google for similar problems. What do you mean with the wrong dimension?

Comment: The dimension of left hand is $\dfrac{m}{s}$ but right $\dfrac{m}{s^2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
your idea is very good, although practically is *impossible*, we want to obtain $v$ straightforward from (1) and (2), we get
$$t^2=\frac{2(x-vt\cos\alpha)}{w}~~~,~~~t^2=\frac{2(y-vt\sin\alpha)}{g}$$
$$\frac{x-vt\cos\alpha}{w}=\frac{y-vt\sin\alpha}{g}$$
where $w$ is wind, thus
$$t=\frac{yw-xg}{v(w\sin\alpha-g\cos\alpha)}\tag{4}$$
substitute (4) in (1):
$$2x=\cancel{v}\cos\alpha\frac{yw-xg}{\cancel{v}(w\sin\alpha-g\cos\alpha)}+\frac12w\left(\frac{yw-xg}{v(w\sin\alpha-g\cos\alpha)}\right)^2$$
Then
$$v^2=\left(\frac{yw-xg}{w\sin\alpha-g\cos\alpha}\right)^2\left(\frac{w(w\sin\alpha-g\cos\alpha)}{4x(w\sin\alpha-g\cos\alpha)-2w\cos\alpha(yw-xg)}\right)\color{blue}{\dfrac{m}{s}}$$

Comment: Holy man, thank you very much! I had quiet a bit to understand that I used the wrong dimensions, but as you show it, it is very understandable! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: I'm happy for this good idea you have posted, any way, you are welcome.